# check particular string is present or not without considering spaces or any newline characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to check a particular string is present in a content without considering space differences or newline characters.

**Case 1**

- input string: `this is a sample test`
- checking word: `asample test`

**Case 2**

- input string: `sample test1 \n new line content`
- checking word : `test1 new`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic where you remove all space characters from both the pattern string and the string to analyze before check if the strings contains the pattern.

**PROTOTYPE:**

```
$input1='this is a sample test';
$inputFiltered1= str_replace('\s', '', $input1);
$pattern1='asample test';
$patternFiltered1= str_replace('\s', '', $pattern1);

$input2='sample test1 \n new line content';
$inputFiltered2= str_replace('\s', '', $input2);
$pattern2='test1 new';
$patternFiltered2= str_replace('\s', '', $pattern2);

if (strpos($inputFiltered1, $patternFiltered1) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}

if (strpos($inputFiltered2, $patternFiltered2) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: And you could comment that by removing `\s` whitespace it also gets around the problem of needing to use DOT ALL in the pattern +1.

Answer (score 0):

Method #1: Pure regex, `$input` is unmodified

```
$pattern='~'.preg_replace('~\S(?!$)\K\s*~','\s*',$check).'~';
if(preg_match($pattern,$input)){
    echo "Found: $check";
}else{
    echo "Did Not Find: $check";
}
```

Method #2: Regex modification of `$input` and `$check`

```
if (strpos(preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $input), preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $check))!==false){
    echo "Found: $check";
}else{
    echo "Did Not Find: $check";
}
```

Method #3: Regex-free modification of `$input` and `$check`

```
$whitechars=[' ',"\t","\r","\n"];  // hardcode whitespace characters
if (strpos(str_replace($whitechars, '', $input), str_replace($whitechars, '', $check))!==false){
    echo "Found: $check";
}else{
    echo "Did Not Find: $check";
}
```

([Demonstrations Link](https://3v4l.org/9ELfu))

Now, you might be asking: "*Which one should I choose for my project?*"

Answering that properly will first depend on the size and content of your `$input` data, then the number of times you'll be running this snippet, then personal preference, and probably least importantly the size and content of `$check`.

1. If your `$input` data is relatively large, then you will want to avoid performing any modifications on the string because of the impact on speed.  Assuming your `$check` string is usually going to be quite small, modifying this value alone is going to produce minimal "drag" on execution time.  As a general answer, I would recommend **Method #1**; although it is using two `preg_` calls, they are processing a very small string.  I should explain that Method #1 only prepares the `$check` value by placing `\s*` between all visible characters.  If there are any whitespace characters in the string, they are removed during pattern preparation (assuming there are no leading or trailing whitespace characters in `$check` -- otherwise, call `trim()` or refine pattern preparation).  ([Method #1 Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvQX6U/1))
2. If you want to prepare both `$input` and `$check` by removing all occurrences of whitespace characters, then the most direct approach would be to call `preg_replace()` on one or more `\s` characters and replace with an empty string (**Method #2**).  This will tell the regex engine to isolate substrings of whitespace(s) and remove them via a "single scan" of the given string.  By comparison, if you want to avoid regex functions, you can use `str_replace()` to perform the same task.  However, using **Method #3** means that you will need to individually "inform" the function of all characters to be removed.  `str_replace()` doesn't know what `\s` means.  Unfortunately, by listing the whitespace character in an array, the function will be performing `n` "iterated scans" of the string AND it can only replace one character at a time.

To crystallize, if you have a string that contains `a[space][newline][newline][tab][space]b`, then `preg_replace()` will scan the string once and make a single replacement.  If you call `str_replace()` on the same string, it will make four scans (remember: `[' ',"\t","\r","\n"]`) and make five separate replacements.

I suppose the message that I am driving home is: Regular Expressions sometimes get a bad rap, but this seems like a compelling case to select a regex method over a non-regex method (unless you benchmark your actual project and find that the regex methods are in fact negatively impacting performance).